# Capturing JSONAPI Included into Angular Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, drupal-8, json-api

I'm trying to learn how to get content from Drupal 8 into my Angular 7 app using jsonapi, starting from Preston So's [book](https://github.com/Apress/decoupled-drupal-in-practice/blob/master/Ch19_ddip-ng/src/app/article.service.ts), Decoupled Drupal in Practice. It stops short of showing how to get resources from relationships and included.

The jsonapi spec offers an include function where I can get related resources from a node without having to make a separate call.

Using http://localhost/jsonapi/node/article/MYUUID?include=field_image presents a nice json object in this general format.

```
jsonapi
data
--attributes
--relationships
included
```

I'm trying to get the included portion but my ArticleService is only getting the contents of the data, and I want to get the included as well.

My article.ts

```
export class Article {
  attributes: object;
  relationships: object;
  included: object;
}
```

My article.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Article } from '../articles/article';
import { Image } from '../articles/image';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ArticleService {
  private articlesUrl = 'http://localhost/jsonapi/node/article';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  getArticle(id: string): Observable<Article>
  {
    if (id) {
      return this.http.get<Article>(this.articlesUrl + '/' + id + '?include=field_image', httpOptions)
        .pipe(
          map(res => res['data'])
         )
        .pipe(
          catchError(this.handleError([]))
    );
    } 
  }
 private handleError<T> (result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
      console.error(error);
      return of(result as T);
    }
  }
}
```

So my first map function is retrieving the data object from the body. I should be able to enlarge that. I attempted setting
`map(res => res['body'])`, then `map(res => res[''])` which returns no object. Reading up on the rxjs/operators I see some operators like mergeMap, concatMap which fail because I'm not understanding how to get the content of the entire body of the response. My searches have yielded little that seems to help, so I'm looking for pointers on how to get the entire body of the response.

Comment: subscribe to getArticle() service from compoent. Observable not get called until you subscribe to it.

Comment: Any reason you are not using a client-side JSON:API library in your Angular application but trying to parse the response manually?

Comment: In my searches, I found some tied to Angular 2. They may help, but I've learned to not add complexity when debugging and researching answers. Thus, it's my ignorance of the available tools that will help and your comment helps. @jelhan

Comment: I think JSON:API mostly pays off if you combine it with a client-side library. The JSON:API payload schema isn't designed to be easily parseable. Especially linking resources require some code. I would not recommend to reimplement that logic over and over again. Not even talking about advanced features like client-side caching, linking and navigating through relationships, allow to reload, update and delete relationships through the links etc.

Comment: Which would you recommend? Or is one written for Angular 2 generally sufficient, pending tweaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**article.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Article } from '../articles/article';
import { Image } from '../articles/image';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ArticleService {
  private articlesUrl = 'http://localhost/jsonapi/node/article';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  getArticle(id: string): Observable<Article>
  {
    if (id) {
      return this.http.get<Article>(this.articlesUrl + '/' + id + '?include=field_image', httpOptions);
    } 
  }
 private handleError<T> (result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
      console.error(error);
      return of(result as T);
    }
  }
}
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ArticleService } from './article.service'; // import ArticleService service from article.service.ts file

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  // inject ArticleService to the component
  constructor(private articleService : ArticleService ) {
    this.getArticle(); call getArticle function onInit
  }
  

  getArticle() {
   const id = 12;  // getting article id 12 details
   // subscribe to getArticle service method will call HTTP request and return response
   this.articleService.getArticle(id).subscribe((response)=> {
      // on successful request this block get called
      console.log('response body');
      console.log(response);
      console.log('response actual data');
      console.log(response.body);
    }, (error)=> {
      // on error this block get called like 404, 500 http status 
  })
  }
}
```

Comment: Here is working demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/santosh-angular-http-response-with-status-code check data in console.

Comment: Hey there! While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: That link to the working demo helped. Mine worked when I removed the Observable<Article> and removed the .pipe(map(res => res['data', 'included']) which opened up to all. If you update your answer to reflect those changes to article.service.ts I'll happily accept.