# How can I use JSON:API along with Angular/RxJs?

Tags: json, angular, json-api

I have a (Laravel) API that is following [json:api spec](https://jsonapi.org/). Everything is working great—using Postman I'm able to make requests for related resources and such.

I am using Angular for my front-end, but I'm struggling to understand how to consume this api.

I have been reading through [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62892332/capturing-jsonapi-included-into-angular-observable) as a starting point.

I am using [ngrx](https://ngrx.io/) for state management; I'm able to successfully make the appropriate request(s) needed to get data from my api. Where I am struggling is how to properly handle the response.

Here is an example response from my request to get an organization:

```
// response from /api/v1/organization/:id

data: {...}
jsonapi: {...}
links: {...}
```

Here is my `Organization` interface:

```
export interface IOrganization {
    data: object;
    jsonapi: object;
    links: object;

    // before json:api I would just use the below attributes
    id?: string;
    name: string;
    streetAddress1: string;
    createdAt?: Date;
    updatedAt?: Date;
    deletedAt?: Date;
}
```

Before using json:api, this class was super straight-forward. But since all of the data is now inside of `data.attributes` I'm not sure how to correctly structure this interface.

Here is what a good portion of my `organization.effects` file looks like:

```
return this._organizationService
    .getOrganization(action.organizationId)
    .pipe(
        tap((organization) => {
            console.log(organization);   // {data:{...}, jsonapi: {...}, data:{...}
        }),
        map((organization) =>
            OrganizationApiActions.loadOrganizationSuccess({
                organization,
            })
   ),
   catchError((error) => {...}
    ...
```

Is the solution to just drill down through the attributes here?

```
organization.data.id;
organization.data.attributes.name;
```

Or is there a more logical way to consume this api? I have seen the [ngx-jsonapi](https://github.com/reyesoft/ngx-jsonapi) package. I don't know if that's overkill here?

In the past using vue.js I have just used the [jsona npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsona)

What is the ideal way to consume a json:api (rest api)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not directly consuming the api as is (backend for frontend) then

- have 2 interface models,

  - one that describes the backend response (ideally codegen or inferred rather than manually written)
  - and the frontend model you want to map to
  - use a function that maps backend object to frontend
  - use on receiving response.

```
const mapJsonApiToOrganization = () =>
  map((response: OrganizationResponse) => {
    const { id, attributes } = response.data;
    return {
      id,
      name: attributes.name,
      streetAddress1: attributes.streetAddress1,
      // ... other mappings
    };
  });

// In your effect
return this._organizationService.getOrganization(action.organizationId).pipe(
  mapJsonApiToOrganization(),
  // from here frontend model only
  map((organization: Organization) => OrganizationApiActions.loadOrganizationSuccess({ organization })),
);
```

Imo I would keep data passed to ngrx frontend model only. If you change your backend you'd want to only change the mapping function.

Using 3rd party packages is a judgement call. If it's just those 5 properties for the frontend model drilling seems fine.

Comment: Hey Andrew! Thank you for your feedback! I am a little new to the Angular world - I didn't realize I could pass a function in the pipe! :) 

I'm not sure I understand "If you're not directly consuming the api as is". I wrote the api and in my angular app, I make a request. I feel like that means I'm directly consuming? Not sure...

I have a handful of models, with many more to come. I got some research to do—thank you again I really appreciate it!

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, "as is" here means response is directly consumed without need for a transformation mapping with the backend doing the relevant mapping. I'm not familiar enough with Laravel to advise but I believe a possibility would be GraphQL as the BFF layer. But directly mapping on response being received is fine too!